# How to set image upload size limit (for example 2mb maximum) in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, ng2-file-upload

we are trying to set a limit on the size of the image like maximum it should be 2mb. We are using ng2-file-upload. You can see the code in the bellow:

```
uploader: FileUploader = new FileUploader({
    url: URL,
    disableMultipart: true
  });
...
...
OnFileSelected(event) {
    const file: File = event[0];

    this.ReadAsBase64(file)
      .then(result => {
        this.selectedFile = result;
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }

  Upload() {
    if (this.selectedFile) {
      this.usersService.AddImage(this.selectedFile).subscribe(
        data => {
          this.socket.emit('refresh', {});
          console.log(data);
        },
        err => console.log(err)
      );
    }
  }

  ReadAsBase64(file): Promise<any> {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    const fileValue = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      reader.addEventListener('load', () => {
        resolve(reader.result);
      });

      reader.addEventListener('error', event => {
        reject(event);
      });

      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    });

    return fileValue;
  }
```

Where and how can we set that limit on the image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [W3 documentation](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#filedata-attr):

> On getting, if the readAsDataURL() read method is used, the result attribute must return a DOMString that is a Data URL [RFC2397] encoding of the File or Blob's data.

So your `reader.result` is either null or a DOMString. A DOMString is string with 16-bit characters.

So, to do size check, you should:

1. Check if `reader.result` is null, if it is, then throw an error or reject the Promise
2. Check the length of your string, knowing that every character is 2 bytes
3. Throw an error if the length*2 is more than 2^20, in fact 2*2^20 is how many bytes there are in 2MB

Now let's translate it in code:

```
  ReadAsBase64(file): Promise<any> {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    const fileValue = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      reader.addEventListener('load', () => {
        const result = reader.result as DOMString;
        if (!result) reject('Cannot read variable');
        if (result.length * 2  > 2**21) reject('File exceeds the maximum size'); // Note: 2*2**20 = 2**21 
        resolve(reader.result);
      });

      reader.addEventListener('error', event => {
        reject(event);
      });

      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    });

    return fileValue;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. So where can I include an error message to notify the user that the image should be less than 2mb for example after trying to upload larger file?

Comment: On `.catch(err => console.log(err));` check the error message (or throw a code) and if it matches, then you can notify the user

Comment: It's basic Promise use

Comment: It says can't find name DOMString

Comment: You have to import the type. But this isn't important (it's just a help for developing). You can remove `as DomString`

Comment: Now it works. Thanks a lot. I will figure out how to display the error when the file is larger since it still displays in the console.

Comment: It displays in the console because it's what you specified to do on error. You did it in this row: `err => console.log(err)`. You can change the behavior here

Comment: I changed console.log(err) into just err and in HTML added  <p *ngIf="err"> {{err}}</p> but it still shows this error in cosole.log: File exceeds the maximum size

Comment: Notice how you have two `catch`es, you have to modify the one after `ReadAsBase64`

Comment: Yes, I did so but the result is the same.